# Difference between AWS Amplify & Apollo Client for GraphQL?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client, aws-appsync, aws-amplify

I agree Apollo Client is a pain to set up because of lots of boilerplate (although it becomes simple after reading the docs) & things like AWS Amplify, URQL, Apollo Boost & Micro GraphQL React makes it easy to work with GraphQL on the client.

I am currently working with AWS AppSync & want to choose between AWS Amplify & Apollo Client & I was thinking of going in all AWS.

So what is the difference between AWS Amplify & Apollo Client?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you use AWS Amplify for connecting with AppSync, it will handle not only the GraphQL queries but also access control with IAM roles. In addition it also provides other essential capabilities, for example features like uploading files to S3, authentication with Cognito & etc.

If you use the Apollo Client which is a more focused library for GraphQL.

Comment: Is that it or anything else? 

I mean I get it, Amplify is made to work with AWS so it will handle all that but I think there is a SDK which if you connect with Apollo, it will do all the things you mentioned. 

Can you elaborate if you have more points to mention?

Comment: The Apollo client also currently has caching capabilities and the AppSync SDK for Apollo will let you do offline programming as well. Depending on your use case, if you don't need all of the features offered by Apollo it might be easier to use Amplify.

Comment: Apollo is faster than Amplify (tested for serverless application that uses a Node12 Lambda). So if time is critical for your application and you are dealing with a lot of data then you should go for Apollo.